# Squarespace header images are cropped by different browsers

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I have noticed that the height of the header image on the pages of our site are cropped, but the amount depends on the browser and the page.

All our header images are uploaded after being sized to 2000 X 1252 px (don't ask, it's historical), all the thumbnails are exactly quarter sized copies of the header images (500 X 313)

A selection of thumbnails can be seen on our home page [nataal.com](http://nataal.com) by
scrolling down slightly.
 Currently the first one is "MUZI" and this thumbnail is rendered correctly. Clicking on the thumbnail takes you to the article's page. Viewing it in MS Edge shows the full width and the majority of the image. About 15% is cropped from the bottom edge. In Firefox much more is cropped, about 40%. I don't believe the image should be cropped at all.

I have tried using the Firefox element inspector, but the height is greyed out and there is no information as to how it is calculated or what css may be involved.

I am quite happy inserting some javascript or css in the "Advanced" tab or tweaking the site css file, but this one has me beat. Is this another "feechur" of Squarespace, or am I doing something really stupid?

This is the image as seen in the Squarespace editor running on Firefox, note it is not cropped
Clicking on the diagonal arrow in the top left corner hides the LH navigation and expands the image to full screen, it is still not cropped.

[image: Squarespace editor version]

As seen in MS Edge

[image: As seen in MS Edge]

As seen in Firefox

[image: As seen in Firefox]

All the above screen shots were taken from the same monitor on the same PC running Windows 10

On the home page, a different type of page, the header image does not get cropped.

Comment: When viewing the website in different browsers, are you making sure to have the browsers at the same width (for example, maximize to full screen) when comparing? Can you add screenshots to your question? The image will scale and crop based on content height and browser width, in order to "fill" the space set by the content; that is a feature. This can all be adjusted, but best that we first understand the problem.

Comment: @Brandon The above screen shots were all taken on the same monitor, maximised to full screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there are two factors going on here:

1. The difference between the browsers may be caused by either A) your zoom level being set differently between the browsers or B) the font rendering between browsers (since the height of the image is based on the text within the page header). Use the keyboard shortcut CTRL+0 to reset the zoom level in each browser to ensure that's not a factor. If that doesn't fix it, it's likely font-related.
2. The image in question is being used in a page header, which is using Squarespace's "ImageLoader" to scale the image so that it fills the space, based on the text/font size and the padding/margin around the text. This is a feature of Squarespace, and you can see it in action by changing the browser width and watching the viewable part of the image change along with it. The key to remember is that, in "responsive" design like this, there is no one-single image size. The image must scale and change aspect ratio based on the device/browser size.

You can read more about point #2 on [Squarespace's own help page about responsive design](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003287447-Responsive-design). Here's an example showing how the visible parts of the image must change in order to maintain the overall aesthetic of the page and readability of text:

[image]

Currently, Squarespace doesn't offer any "art direction"-based image options. That is, there currently is no way to specify specific images for mobile vs. desktop, for example, though in some cases it can be "faked" with Javascript and/or CSS.

If you want to modify the height of the image, you must instead modify the height of the content which the height of the image is based on. The height of the image is based on the "MUZI Words Binwe Adebayo" text. The image is set to fill the background of the area that these words occupy.

For example, you may set the image to be at least the height of the browser viewport by using:

```
.title-desc-wrapper.has-main-image {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

If that's not the effect you want, you can instead specify your own top/bottom padding for the inner-description element like this:

```
.title--description-position-over-image.title--description-alignment-center .title-desc-inner {
    padding-top: 280px; /* or 20vw or whatever you like... */
    padding-bottom: 280px;
}
```

You can of course play with those values.

What you're seeing is that the height of the image is related to the height of the text, so by adjusting the height of the text description (either via padding, min-height or other properties), the image height is adjusted (because ImageLoader is set to set the image size based on the text).

The possibilities are limitless as far as what values you might set to get the look you want. But as long as you keep in mind that you should be adjusting the height of the text/description, you'll have greater success.

Keep in mind it may be necessary to use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and/or `!important` to set the height of the text/image to your liking at every width/breakpoint. That is why it is very time consuming to be very particular about image cropping/aspect-ratio in Squarespace (and responsive design in general, to some degree): it's very difficult to know exactly what size the text will be on every version of every browser on every operating system on every device.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, but both browsers are set on zero zoom when the screen shots were taken. So the only thing that changed was the browser. However I did notice that, if I went away from full screen and narrowed the window (something I hadn't tried - duh!), the height allocated remained the same whilst the image scaled in width, which meant more of the image came into view vertically until it was all visible. So the maximum height (aspect ratio ?) must be getting set somewhere, I just can't figure out where.

Comment: Ok @pjaj - I updated the answer to generalize point #1 and to add possible solutions, example CSS and explanations to the end.

Comment: Brandon, once again thank you. The first, simple line of CSS does the trick. Just as a quick pre-test, I inserted 3 off <br> tags after the main header text and this also caused the image to expand vertically, but, of course, pushed the sub-heading down too far. I never realised that it was the text that governed the image height. I will now, cautiously, add it to the site-wide css file.